# Android how to restrict user to upload a image less than 2MB

Tags: android

In my android application i am uploading a image but if the size is greater than 2MB it crashes.
Anybody having the solution to stop the user to upload the image greater than 2MB

Thanx in advance....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you expect from a general question like that without any specifics, but a general question gets a general answer:

1. Check image size. Depending on the format you can use the correct API for that.
2. Compare image size to 2MB.
3. Restrict if size is too large.

Answer (score 0):

I also got these "out of memory" issue when I worked on images. But I problem is that the image dimemsion is to big. I post my solution for it, hope it can help u out.

```
BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
o2.inSampleSize=0.5;
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
```